# terraform GCP VPC connector creation issue

Tags: networking, google-cloud-platform, terraform, cloud, terraform-provider-gcp

### Overview

I tried creating a VPC network, having a subnet and adding a Serverless VPC connector with terraform in GCP. I was following the official guide ( https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-serverless-vpc-access#terraform ) and initially everything was working well. After that I accidently commited my JSON  key to github, someone stole it and used it for crypto, the project was disabled but shortly after that reinstated

After that my terraform VPC connector creations started to fail. I tried a lot of different things but nothing seems to work(running destroy, changine service accounts, changing names, deleting all of the terraform subfolders, deleting EVERY resource and restarting the process)

The errors I am getting are:

```
│ Error: Error waiting to create Connector: Error waiting for Creating Connector: Error code 13, message: An internal error occurred: Failed to create a VPC Access connector. Please delete the connector manually.
│
```

or

```
│ Error: Error creating Connector: googleapi: Error 409: Requested entity already exists
```

Today I tried to create VPC connector from the command line(gcloud) and from the UI tool. The errors persisted

```
Unknown error. Original error message: Operation failed: Insufficient CPU quota in region.
Max throughput of the connector per day over last seven days.
```

or

```
An internal error occurred: Failed to create a VPC Access connector. Please delete the connector manually.
```

#### errors while deleting:

```
│ Error: Error waiting for Deleting Network: The network resource 'projects/static-emblem-327016/global/networks/sun-serverless-network' is already being used by 'projects/static-emblem-327016/global/routes/default-route-5cbc9de02e21bb35'
│
```

I was lookint at this issue https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/164378672 In it I was problems with us-central1 but I tried a couple of different regions and still I have the same issue

### Questions:

I am running out of ideas, I was wondering if this is an infrastructural issue, maybe I should dump the project and create a new one ? Where can I check if there are infra issues ? How can I resolve my issue?

Answer (score 1):

I recently get this error `Error: Error creating Connector: googleapi: Error 409: Requested entity already exists`. So I can explain the root cause and it's fix.

What I was doing is like trying to create a GCP resource (Create PubSub topic) using terraform (plan and then apply).

But before executing the `terraform apply`, I created the resource manually long time back with the same name. I expected that the `terraform plan` or `terraform apply` will not try to create it again since the resource name is same. But instead of `Refreshing state`, I found it was trying to `Creating` the resource. The reason it that, terraform does not know about your resource history. Either you need to import your resource history using `terraform import` command or else delete the manually created resource and then run the `terraform apply` command.

Comment: I tried deleting litterally evey terraform configuration file in my repo, every bucket, every network every instance, every resource, after that I tried rerunning the terraform init plan and apply and issue persisted

Comment: Did you deleted the resources manually using gcloud/from UI console or using `terraform destroy`? Try delete them manually using gcloud/from UI console and then run the `terraform apply`.

Comment: I tried both, I tried with the `terraform destroy`, I tried from the UI. I tried from the deleting it from the UI and then deleting the `.terraform` folder. The issue persists. The problem is that the issue persist even if I try creating these VPC connectors from the UI and from gcloud CLI

Comment: Have you used something like this in your terraform code `backend "gcs" {
    bucket = "abc-gcp-project-name"
    prefix = "xyz-storage-bucket-name/directory"
  }`

If yes, then try to rename the bucket name or use a new bucket name and give a try. I suspect it hold up the existing resources history there and therefore it always says 'already exist'.

Comment: I have created a new project. In it I created manually a network and subnet and VPC connector and everythong was ok. After that I retried to do the same thing with terraform and the error appeared again. After my terraform run I am not able to make VPC serverless connectors from the UI

Comment: Also I tried removing all buckets from the project. I am not using any backend "gcs" stuff but I used to have a bucket... but I removed it .... nothing changes

Answer (score 0):

The message “An internal error occurred: Failed to create a VPC Access connector. Please delete the connector manually” can indicate that you don't have enough resources in your project to create the connector. Please make sure you have enough [Resource Quota](https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas#checking_your_quota) available in your GCP project.

The message [“googleapi: Error 409: Requested entity already exists”](https://cloud.google.com/apis/design/errors) indicates that The resource that a client tried to create already exists.

If you want to know what the root cause is, you can check the logs of the VPC Connector creation in the System Event Audit Logs.

> System Event audit logs contain log entries for Google Cloud actions that modify the configuration of resources. System Event audit logs are generated by Google systems; they aren't driven by direct user action. System Event audit logs are always written; you can't configure, exclude, or disable them. The instructions to access them [are here](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/audit#viewing_audit_logs).

On the other hand, generating and distributing service account keys poses severe security risks to your organization. They are long-lived credentials that are not automatically rotated. These keys can be leaked accidentally or maliciously allow attackers to gain access to your sensitive GCP resources. If you accidentally compromised your JSON Key, please read the recommendations [in this link](https://cloud.google.com/security/compromised-credentials).
If you want to know more about the risk and alternatives to download Service Account, Key please [follow this link](https://jryancanty.medium.com/stop-downloading-google-cloud-service-account-keys-1811d44a97d9). Please note that this is not GCP official documentation, so I cannot vouch for its accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve my issue. It turns out that I had deleted my default compute engine service account in panic. I was able to recover it and everything worked out from there. For more info go here: https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts#undeleting_a_service_account

you have to identify the default service acc for compute engine and undelete it:
`gcloud beta iam service-accounts undelete ACCOUNT_ID`